# Определить количество чисел в самой длинной последовательности чисел, расположенных по убыванию

Tags: c++, массивы

Всем привет, скажу все коротко и ясно. Есть задача: Определить количество чисел в
самой длинной последовательности чисел, расположенных по убыванию. Написал программу но считает не правильно, ответ должен быть 5, выводит 6 и так далее, но если написать сила от 25 до 1, ответ правильный. Как это понимать? Объясните, пожалуйста, код ниже:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int MyFunc(int MyArr[25]);

int main() {
    int arr[25];

    cout << "Eneter elements:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i != 25; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }


    cout << "Max len: " << MyFunc(arr);
}

int MyFunc(int MyArr[25]) {
    int count = 0, max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i != 25; i++) {
        if (MyArr[i + 1] < MyArr[i]) {
            count++;
            if (count > max) {
                max = count;
            }
        }
        else{
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, вы выходите за рамки массива, во-вторых, даже наличии 2 чисел в последовательности вы считаете их как 1 (инициализируя `count` нулем).

```
int MyFunc(int MyArr[25])
{
    int count = 1, max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
    {
        if (MyArr[i+1] < MyArr[i]) {
            count++;
            if (count > max) {
                max = count;
            }
        }
        else{
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: там лишние проверки во вложенном if в таком случае и лишние присваивание происходят.

Comment: с while намного понятнее логика получается.

Comment: Можно перенести проверку на максимум, да. Я просто старался поменьше менять код ТС. Подправил ответ. Что до `while` — можно, но тогда надо лишний раз изменять и отслеживать значение индекса. Код только сложнее получается, но не эффективнее.

Comment: его можно сделать эффективнее. увеличиваем на 1 последовательность и добавляем фиктивную запись равную MAX_INTEGER в конце - в результате будет вообще не нужно проверять выход за границы массива.

Comment: Если все 25 элементов будут расположены по убыванию, тогда ответ 0, нужно проверку на это добавить)

Comment: внутрь else нельзя в общем случае делать, не будет учитывать последовательность последняя в таком случае.

Comment: @xmikex Тогда тем более, так и чувствовал подвох в вашем предложении... :)

Comment: ну за пределами цикла добавить одну проверку лучше, чем куча проверок внутри.

Comment: А вообще, если внимательно прочитать задание - то это все не решения. Если там нет речи о непрерывной последовательности, то ведь надо вообще по-другому проверять, то есть будет 7,10,6,10,5,10,4,10,3,10 -  то тут то есть убывающая последовательность, только индекс через 1. Интересно, что именно имелось ввиду под последовательность в задании.